# Storing user input (ul) in a to do list so that the list appears when the program is reopened

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, store

I am working on a project for my dad's boss. I created a to do list using HTML, JS, and CSS. I'm really out of my element in terms of how to make it so that the list of things that he enters automatically saves, so that if he closes the file, the list is still there when he opens it

I don't want anyone to code this for me. I don't want anyone to write the code for me, because I really want to learn how to think through these things more efficiently, but if someone could help talk me though what I need to do, I would appreciate it.

Comment: On keyEnter event you can trigger save in background.

Comment: That's awesome @C Red, You can watch a tutorial video or read up on articles on how to use JavaScript's localStorage api, or IndexedDB api. You can also read up a tutorial on building a todolist with IndexedDB All the best

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your application does not involve any server-side logic, so I only discuss **client side** options:

When the todo-List is getting changed you need to store the content and load it again when the page is revisited/loaded. Therefore you basically have the options of saving the data to a cookie or to local storage. Cookies are intended to save small data client-side and to transfer this data with every request to the server. Cookies also usually have a limited time to live before they are deleted. 
Localstorage can store bigger data client side, is not sent with every request to the server and will usually be not deleted as quick as cookies. So I think I would prefer using localstorage.

There are nice references on writing and reading to cookies and localstorage.

**Localstorage**

see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
...
var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

**Cookies**

see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
...
var x = document.cookie;
```

But you should understand that as long as you rely on saving your data to the client the data will **not be available in another browser** (e.g. you worked in chrome and now open the page in firefox or in incognito mode).

So longterm you should **consider** to transfer and save the data **server-side**. If you insist in using a pure client-side approach, I would recommend to implement the option to save the todo-list as a download. Otherwise the **deletion of browser-data might result in loss of all your todo-lists.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is a **web application** that's able to store information, on this case your information is the TODO list you mensioned. You can store this information on a **database** or a .txt for example. After that, the next step is to fill the list you created everytime you load your html page, to save new information you can set an **event** in js saving the information in the background. 
Of course to do all this you need to do some research on the key points I've mensioned.